# Iterating through two tables to find common values, and if it exists replace value in one column

Tags: python, for-loop, comparison

I have two tables , TABLE1 AND TABLE2. One with just Project IDs and another with Project ID and Task ID. 
I want to iterate through TABLE1 and compare it to TABLE2 Projects IDs. If there is a common value, I want to attach the Task ID corresponding to that particular Project ID to TABLE1 Project ID.

The way I did this is as follows.

```
for index,i in enumerate(TABLE1["ProjectID"]):

  if i in TABLE2["ProjectID"].values:

    TABLE1["TaskId"][index] =TABLE2["TaskId"].loc[TABLE2["TaskId"]==i].values[0]
  else:        
    print("Doesnt exist")
```

Is there a better way of doing this? It took me ages to do this, even if its just a few line of code!
Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `merge`

```
new_table = pd.merge(Table1,Table2,how='left',on='ProjectID')
```

go through [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: Thankyou ! This works! But what about the situation when, I do not want to delete any of my data. For example, in the above example, I would like to put NA if the ProjectID is not found.